# My first drag and drop, it works but is it best practice?

Tags: jquery, draggable

I've just started learning javascript and have created a drag and drop using jquery draggable.

The demo is here:

http://www.vwardv.com/doll6.html

I couldn't find a tutorial so I just went on to the jquery site and played around with adapting the demo. It works but I have no idea if I've coded it the way it should actually be coded. I would be really grateful if you could tell me if you see anything you would improve.

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable()
});
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
});
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable3" ).draggable();
});
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable4" ).draggable();
});
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable5" ).draggable();
});
</script>


</head>
</body>

<div id="bodies/palepd.gif">
<img src="bodies/palepd.gif" class="ui-widget-content" id="draggable">
<img src="bodies/trousers.gif" class="ui-widget-content" id="draggable2">
<img src="bodies/top.gif" class="ui-widget-content" id="draggable3">
<img src="bodies/dress.gif" class="ui-widget-content" id="draggable4">
<img src="bodies/coat.gif" class="ui-widget-content" id="draggable5">
</div>
```

Thank you

Vic

**update***

Thank you for all your advice, I really appreciate it. I have now adjusted the code according to your advice. Let me know if I've misunderstood anything or if there's anything further I could improve. Thank you

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".mydraggable" ).draggable();
});
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="items">
<img src="bodies/palepd.gif" class="mydraggable">
<img src="bodies/trousers.gif" class="mydraggable">
<img src="bodies/top.gif" class="mydraggable">
<img src="bodies/dress.gif" class="mydraggable">
<img src="bodies/coat.gif" class="mydraggable">
</div>


</body>
```

***update 2**

Can anyone tell me why I should us 'ui-widget-content' instead of 'mydraggble'?

Now I need to move on to the next stage, which is ordering the items so for example, you can put a top behind a jacket etc.

I will need to add two buttons to the page: one will move an item up a layer/layers, and one will move it down a layer/layers. This will obviously mean I will need to build in some means indicating which item is selected, for clarity. Can anyone point me in the right direction for both/either of these things?

Thanks again

Comment: The biggest issue is definitely that her pants don't fit at all. Definitely the biggest ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be better to replace those 5 separate script blocks with one:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#draggable, #draggable2, #draggable3, #draggable4, #draggable5" ).draggable()
});
</script>
```

Even better would be to give a class 'mydraggable' to every draggable element on your page and them replace the above with:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $( ".mydraggable" ).draggable()
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted to know. I thought that there must be something like that. I've changed the code and its working, is this what you intended:

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply call all objects in one jQuery selector:

```
$('.ui-widget-content').draggable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly fine :)

`</body>` should be `<body>` and then close it and `</html>` at the end.

```
<div id="bodies/palepd.gif">
```

This is an invalid ID.

Combine all your inline script blocks into a single block:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable1, #draggable2, #draggable3, #draggable4, #draggable5" ).draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that leaps out at me is the number of ready event handlers that you have. Each instance of `$(function() { ...` is a ready event handler that is executed when the DOM is ready for manipulation.

There is no need to have so many when one would suffice:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable()
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
    $( "#draggable3" ).draggable();
    $( "#draggable4" ).draggable();
});
```

The next problem is the missing semi-colon on the first line of the function body. While it's not a major problem, I would always recommend including the semi-colon at the end of a line. You will likely run into confusing problems later if you don't.

Next, you could replace those 4 lines with one, much shorter line. As all 4 elements share a common class, you can use a class selector to match all of them:

```
$(function() {
    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable();
});
```

Also, you never open the `<body>` element, only close it. Change `</body>` to `<body>` and close it at the end.

Finally, when there is no `src` attribute present on a `<script>` element, the `type` attribute must be present. As you are writing JavaScript code within that `<script>` element, a `type` of `text/javascript` would be needed. Other HTML-validity problems are the missing `<title>` element and missing `alt` attributes on the `<img>` elements.

So all in all, I would change your code to this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".ui-widget-content").draggable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bodies/palepd.gif">
        <img src="bodies/palepd.gif" class="ui-widget-content">
        <img src="bodies/trousers.gif" class="ui-widget-content">
        <img src="bodies/top.gif" class="ui-widget-content">
        <img src="bodies/dress.gif" class="ui-widget-content">
        <img src="bodies/coat.gif" class="ui-widget-content">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Regarding the `type` attribute: I don't think you have to include it in any case. The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) says: *"The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is `"text/javascript"`."* This is independent from the `src` attribute.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The following line of the spec clarifies it further: *If the language is not that described by "`text/javascript`", then the type attribute must be present*. You learn something new every day :)

Comment: here's a stupid question for you: what's the reason for using ui-widget-content instead of mydraggable? It says to use ui-widget-content on the jquery website but I dont understand why.

Comment: It's just an arbitrary name, you can use whatever you want. Since you had used `ui-widget-content` in your question, I used it here too. You can use whatever class name you feel appropriate. In my opinion, `mydraggable` would be a better fit as it goes some way to describing the purpose of the elements.